# Azure Build and Deploy not Including node_modules and assets folders

Tags: visual-studio, azure, npm

I am using Azure to build and deploy a webapp. The problem I'm having with it is that it is not archiving/copying src files that aren't included in the project. These source files include node_modules and some assets.

I definitely don't want these included in the project because I don't want VS tracking/indexing them. They also may change a lot without me knowing and trying to manage what's in the csproj would be a nightmare.

[image]

Is there a step I need to take to copy over files not included in the project?

**EDIT**

In the meantime. I've included asset folders and i'm doing an `npm install` manually on the server. I am not happy with this and may switch node for my web "project" if I cannot resolve this.

If anyone knows the solution thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm struggling with the same problem right now.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Anything that is not included in the project is ignored when publishing the artifact. Right now I go into the azure console and run npm install when a new deployment occurs. This is not ideal and I intend to revisit this in the future. Maybe explore adding node_modules to `App_Data` or something. Let me know if you figure something out.